# Bash outputs strange environment line for every command and echos command

Tags: bash

On an Amazon Linux instance, for EVERY command entered into bash, it outputs

```
printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
```

It does not matter what command is entered.  For example

```
$ date
date
Mon Oct 14 17:15:31 UTC 2019
printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
```

and

```
$ ls -all
ls -all
total 1776
drwx------ 5 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Oct 14 17:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root        4096 Sep  2 14:18 ..
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user    5853 Oct 11 21:43 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user      18 Aug 30  2017 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user     193 Aug 30  2017 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user     124 Aug 30  2017 .bashrc
drwx------ 3 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Oct 14 15:22 .cache
drwx------ 4 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Oct 14 15:22 .local
drwx------ 2 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Sep  2 14:18 .ssh
printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
```

and it also echos the commands too.

> What is happening here, and how to I stop this behavior?

Comment: What is your `PS1` environment variable set to?

Comment: @AFH  `[\u@\h \W]\$` is what is returned when I enter `echo $PS1`

Comment: `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with the Terminal. No matter what Value the `$PS1` Environment Variable has, it gets translated into a `bash` `printf` Shell-Scripting Command. What is the Value of your `$TERM` Environment Variable? Are you sure that you are using the _Bourne-Again_ Shell and not another Shell, other than relating to the presence of those four `.bash*` Files?

Comment: @Cyrus  Thank you, that worked.  Any ideas on what caused this in the first place?

Comment: @RoyHinkley: Sorry, I don't know anything about Amazon Linux.

Comment: @Cyrus Please move your comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set incorrectly in one of the files that Bash processes at startup. Possible causes could be found there:

- /etc/profile
- /etc/bash.bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bashrc

A quick workaround / test:

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```